# Client side filtering order text messages by timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently it is displaying text messages sent on the left and then text messages received on the right.However,i would like the text messages of both received and send to be sorted by timestamp at one go(Currently it sorts sent first by timestamp then display the sent messages and then next then it sorts received messages by timestamp then display the received messages.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadPosts()
    loadPostsReceivedMessage()
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatCollectionViewCell    
     let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

//Setup the messageReceived and messageSent
        if chats[indexPath.row].senderID == senderIDNumber {
        if let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message{
            let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
            cell.messageSend.frame = CGRect(x:8,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
            cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
         //showOutgoingMessage(text: chats[indexPath.row].message)
    }
            cell.messageSend.text = chats[indexPath.row].message
        }
    else {
            cell.messageReceived.text = chats[indexPath.row].message
            let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message
            let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText!).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
            cell.messageReceived.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 30,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
            cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 30,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 4, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
if let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message {
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
}

//Get Message sent
  func loadPosts() {
    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
    chatsRef.whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!).whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            for document in documents {
                let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                guard let sender = document.data()["sender"] as? String else {return}
               // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                guard let profileUrl = document.data()["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
self.chats.append(chat)
print(self.chats)
self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
}
}


//Get message received
func loadPostsReceivedMessage() {
   /* let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let currentUser = dic["username"] as? String
            let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        } */
            let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
            print("thecurrentreceiver"+senderString)
            print("thecurrentsender"+receiverIDNumber)
    chatsRef.whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: senderString).whereField("sender", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    for document in documents {
                        let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                        let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                        let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                        let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                        // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                        guard let profileUrl = document.data()["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                        guard let sender = document.data()["sender"] as? String else {return}
                        let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!,profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
                        print("whatisthemessage"+messageText!)
                        self.chats.append(chat)
                        print(self.chats)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: Something like "  chats.sort {
            (element1, element2) -> Bool in
            return element1.message! < element2.timestamp
        }" but i'm not sure thus will need help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set up yourself for this trouble. Why dont you just use this structure:

```
  -chats
   --chatID
      ---senderID
      ---receiverID
```

This way every message, that comes in, is a document named after the sender's id. Then when when you want to `loadPosts()` the snapshot it is in chronological order and the only thing you have to do is to position them right or left according to who the sender is.